# How to type ":" ("colon") in regexp?

Tags: java, regex

`:` ("colon") has a special meaning in regexp, but I need to use it as is, like `[A-Za-z0-9.,-:]*`.
I have tried to escape it, but this does not work `[A-Za-z0-9.,-\:]*`

Comment: Maybe you need two backslashes for escaping it?

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

In most regex implementations (including Java's), `:` has no special meaning, neither inside nor outside a character class.

Your problem is most likely due to the fact the `-` acts as a range operator in your class:

```
[A-Za-z0-9.,-:]*
```

where `,-:` matches all ascii characters between `','` and `':'`. Note that it still matches the literal `':'` however!

Try this instead:

```
[A-Za-z0-9.,:-]*
```

By placing `-` at the start or the end of the class, it matches the literal `"-"`. As mentioned in the comments by Keoki Zee, you can also escape the `-` inside the class, but most people simply add it at the end.

A demo:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("8:".matches("[,-:]+"));      // true: '8' is in the range ','..':'
        System.out.println("8:".matches("[,:-]+"));      // false: '8' does not match ',' or ':' or '-'
        System.out.println(",,-,:,:".matches("[,:-]+")); // true: all chars match ',' or ':' or '-'
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also escape the hyphen with a backslash, `[a\-z]`.

Comment: @Keoki: true, although I find it clearer to do as little escaping (double escaping inside Java string literals!) as possible. Still, it's good to mention one _can_ escape it as well.

Comment: Placing the hyphen at the end is probably what the previous programmer did, which led to this error. I *always* escape it: end the cycle `:)`

Comment: @Kobi, someone who doesn't know `-` is special inside a character class, shouldn't meddle with regex! :). In all seriousness though, yeah, yours is the safer option for sure!

Comment: @BartKiers True, but SO is also a place where people come to learn. The main reason I found myself here is because I had trouble capturing a colon, and although my problem wasn't the same, the answer, helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 11):

Be careful, `-` has a special meaning with regexp. In a `[]`, you can put it without problem **if it is placed at the end**. In your case, `,-:` is taken as **from `,` to `:`**.

Answer (score 6):

Colon does not have special meaning in a character class and does not need to be escaped.  According to [the PHP regex docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php), the only characters that need to be escaped in a character class are the following:

> All non-alphanumeric characters other
>   than `\`, `-`, `^` (at the start) and the
>   terminating `]` are non-special in
>   character classes, but it does no harm
>   if they are escaped.

For more info about Java regular expressions, see [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: I do not understand why this got a downvote, can someone explain to me what might be wrong with this answer please?

Comment: I didn't vote down but maybe because you link PHP regex documentation in a Java regex question?

Answer (score -3):

use `\\:` instead of `\:`.. the `\` has special meaning in java strings.

Comment: While it is true that the backslash is an escape character in Java strings, escaping the backslash here won't solve the problem, since `:` isn't a special char in regex anyway.