# Understanding `+` in regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression to remove all usernames from tweets. It looks like this:

```
regexFinder = "(?:\\s|\\A)[@]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+):";
```

I'm trying to understand what each component does. So far, I've got:

```
(       Used to begin a “group” element
?:      Starts non-capturing group (this means one that will be removed from the final result)
\\s     Matches against shorthand characters
|       or
\\A     Matches at the start of the string and matches a position as opposed to a character
[@]     Matches against this symbol (which is used for Twitter usernames)
+       Match the previous followed by
([A-Za-z0-9- ]  Match against any capital or small characters and numbers or hyphens
```

I'm a bit lost with the last bit though. Could somebody tell me what the +): means? I'm assuming the bracket is ending the group, but I don't get the colon or the plus sign.

If I've made any mistakes in my understanding of the regex please feel free to point it out!

Comment: In all cases when outside a bracket and not preceded by a \ the + means "one or more of whatever is immediately in front of me"

Comment: `+` matches one or more of whatever comes immediately before it.  So, `[A-Za-z0-9-_]+` matches a sequence of *at least* one alphanumeric character, hyphen or underscore.

Comment: [Explain Regular Expressions](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` actually means "one or more" of whatever it follows.

In this case `[@]+` means "one or more @ symbols" and `[A-Za-z0-9-_]+` means "one or more of a letter, number, dash, or underscore". The `+` is one of several quantifiers, [learn more here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

The colon at the end is just making sure the match has a colon at the end of the match.

Sometimes it helps to see a visualization, here is one generated by [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/):

[image]

Comment: So just to ask, does that mean it will run through everything after the @ statement until it finds something not in the group 1 of your diagram, or until it finds a colon?

Comment: @AndrewMartin It will look for one of the items in group 1 until it doesn't match. Then it (that group of letters/numbers/hyphens/underscores) must be followed by a colon or it wont match the regex.

Comment: @AndrewMartin, no problem. Also, in case you were curious. If your group1 contained `:` as well, it wouldn't eat up the colon at the end. For example, if you ran `([a-z:]+):` on "abadsf:sdfas:", the group would capture "abadsf:sdfas" (not including the colon at the end). Where-as if you made it non-greedy like `([a-z:]+?):` it would actually match "abadsf:" first, with "abadsf" being group1. Not that this is really pertinent to your question I guess :)

Comment: Apologies, thought I had. Done now.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` sign means "the previous character can be repeated 1 or more times". This is in contrast to the `*` symbol, which means "the previous character can be repeated **0** or more times". The colon, as far as I can tell, is literal—it matches a literal `:` in the string.

Comment: So just to ask, does that mean it will run through everything after the @ statement until it finds something not in the group 1 of your diagram, or until it finds a colon?

Answer (score 1):

The plus sign in regular expressions means "one or more occurrences of the previous character or group of characters." Since the second plus sign is within the second set of parentheses, it basically means that the second set of parentheses matches any string comprised of at least one lowercase or uppercase letter, number, or hyphen.

As for the colon, it doesn't have any meaning in Java's regex class. If you're not sure, [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579921/how-to-type-colon-in-regexp) already found out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we shall see..

```
[@]+                 any character of: '@' (1 or more times)
   (                 group and capture to \1:
    [A-Za-z0-9-_]+   any character of: (a-z A-Z), (0-9), '-', '_' (1 or more times)
   )                 end of capture group \1
   :                 look for and match ':'
```

The following quantifiers are recognized:

```
*      Match 0 or more times
+      Match 1 or more times
?      Match 1 or 0 times
{n}    Match exactly n times
{n,}   Match at least n times
{n,m}  Match at least n but not more than m times
```